# add data to ReplaySubject<ImpiantoModel[]> but not overwrite with next()

Tags: angular, rxjs, httpclient, observable, angular-services

I'm new to angular and I have a problem. 
I'm using `ReplaySubject` for share data between component and I got it BUT how can I update my data?

I'd like to add every minute a value from http het but with `Next()` method I overwrite all the data.

So here are my files:

data-service.service.ts

```
import {Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { Observable  } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import {ImpiantoModel} from './impianto.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataServiceService implements OnInit {
private myUrl = ('https://my-json.server.typicode.com/nicscap/fake_json/ImpiantiProva');


myData: ReplaySubject<ImpiantoModel[]> = new ReplaySubject();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

stream$(): Observable<ImpiantoModel[]> {
    return this.myData.asObservable();
}


ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get<ImpiantoModel[]>(this.myUrl)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
        this.myData.next(data);
});
return this.myData;
}

private newdata = [
 {
 'nomeImpianto': 'MFL8',
 'descrImpianto': 'Multifilo 8',
 'posizione': 'Place8',
 'dati_status': 'Place8',
 'unita_misura': 'm/s'
 },
];

pushData() {
   this.myData.next(this.newdata);
 }

}
```

So on `data-service.service.ts` I make http request and I'd like that `pushData()` append the `newdata` but it overwrite.

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataServiceService} from './data-service.service';
import {ImpiantoModel} from './impianto.model';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'app';

systems: ImpiantoModel[];

constructor(private _dataService: DataServiceService) {}

getdata() {
   this._dataService.stream$().subscribe(
      result => this.systems = result
      );
}

 ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService.ngOnInit();
    this.getdata();
 }
}
```

I want that by pushing “pushdata” the new datas are insert after the previous datas, and not overwritten on them. How can I do?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [scan](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator to accumulate values over time

```
myData: ReplaySubject<ImpiantoModel> = new ReplaySubject();
stream$: Observable<ImpiantoModel[]>;

constructor(){
    this.stream$ = this.myData
        .asObservable
        // append current value on previous array
        .scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, curr], []);
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subject-with-scan?file=app/app.component.ts) demoing this.

Comment: hi, first of all, happy new year! 
I try your solution and it works!!! I'm happy of that but I have a new problem: how can I show the value on html page? I have an Observable and it doesn't work with ngFor! 
ps: here you can find the example and [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subject-with-scan-lcd7lp). I hope you can help me again! thank!!

Comment: @NicolòScapin Happy new year! since you are passing an observable to ngFor you must use the async pipe to subscribe to the data. `<div *ngFor="let system of stream$ | async">`

Comment: thanks again for quick reply, but if I change the code for *ngFor it doesn't work. do I have to change something in the component?

Comment: @NicolòScapin there are a couple issues in the code. The main one is you are passing in the data from the api (an array) to the subject when the subject expects a single object. Check out this [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subject-with-scan-ee9jgb?file=app/app.component.ts) You can fiddle with the subject and tell it to accept an array instead if you like

Comment: WOW! wonderful! fantastic, this is just what I was looking for!
Now I proceed with my work, in particular:
- update of the fields
- use arrays inside arrays
- remove a value in the array

thank you so much for your time!

Comment: @NicolòScapin np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

If the http response is an array, you just need concat the results.

```
  this._dataService.stream$().subscribe((result) => {
      this.systems = this.systems.concat(result) // here
  });
```